# Can I simplify this for loop?

Tags: java, refactoring

The following segment of code is from a system that generates a 5 by 5 grid of JButtons. I need to iterate over an `ArrayList` of `JButtons` and pass the row and column of the `JButton` into the `ButtonListener`'s constructor. The way the code is currently shown below works, but I was wondering if I could clean up the code at all or re-factor in any way. I seem to have a lot of instructions for trying to construct a grid.

```
    int row = 1, col = 1;
    for (JButton curButton : view.getButtons()) {

        curButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener(row, col));
        row++;

        if (row > 5) {
            row = 1;
            col++;
        }           
    }
```

Is there any way I can improve the quality or simplify the above code segment?

Comment: Why not just use a traditional double for loop with `i` and `j` instead of `row` and `col`? **Edit**: They could continue being called `row` and `col` if you like and still be incremented correctly with a double for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int iterator = 0;
for (JButton curButton : view.getButtons()) {

    curButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener(iterator%5 + 1, iterator/5 + 1));

    iterator++; 
}
```

Note here that I'm using integer division, which always rounds down. `iterator/5 + 1` will map {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,...} to {1,1,1,1,1,2,2...}

Comment: This seems like the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you have:

```
col = row = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < col; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
         curButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener(i, j));
    }
}
```

Might have to make col and row 6 or make i and j start at a different number.

Comment: This doesn't allow a new `ButtonListener` to be added to every `JButton` in  `view.getButtons()`.